# Bootstrap modal fade div not active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

first of all I barely know what I am doing so I most likely have a simple syntax error. I am trying to use this site [bootleaf](http://bmcbride.github.io/bootleaf/) as a template for some maps I am making. I would like the about button to work for me as it does at the bootleaf site but mine doesnt appear to become active. if you click on my button [here](http://davemetzler.github.io/maps/classicdenver/) you will see what I am talking about. here is all of my code for the modal including the jquery.

BOOTSTRAP 3.3.1 JQUERY 1.11.1

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" id="about-btn"><i class="fa fa-question-circle white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a></li>

div class="modal fade" id="aboutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome to the glory of History!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="aboutTabs">
          <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;About the project</a></li>

         <!--  <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Contact us</a></li> -->
          <li><a href="#disclaimer" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;Disclaimer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutGIS" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;About the GIS stuff</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="aboutTabsContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="aboutGIS">
            <p>This map represents the integration of several much smarter peoples tools which include <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap 3</a>,  <a href="http://mapbox.com/" target="_blank">MapBox</a>,
              <a href="http://leafletjs.com/" target="_blank">Leaflet</a>,  <a href="http://osmbuildings.org/" target="_blank">OSMBuildings</a>, and the work of <a href="https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf" target="_blank">Brian McBride</a>. I have taken some static maps off of the Denver Public Library’s website, gave them the good old GIS treatment and brought them to you! </p>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">Data</div>
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">The Sanborn Maps come from The DPL public map collection</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">The Buildings are courtesy of OSM Buildings</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">You can get imagery anywhere but this fine example is from ESRI.</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Modern roads from the fine folks at GeoIQ.</li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="disclaimer" class="tab-pane fade text-danger">
            <p>This is all here in good fun.</p>
            <p> I have made every attempt to utilize best georeferencing practices but the original files were a bit of a mess to work with. Consequently some of the blocks are a little off but I think everyone gets the idea! It was a bit of a process to get the images and stitch them together which is why they are incomplete but still, History!</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="about">
            <p>fill me with knowledge.</p>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">Features</div>
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and here is the jquery:

```
 $("#about-btn").click(function() {
  $("#aboutModal").modal("show");
  return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed some of your HTML: Your `li` is not a valid markup since it's not enclosed within a `ul` and then you were missing an opening bracket when declaring your modal.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" id="about-btn"><i class="fa fa-question-circle white"></i>About</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="aboutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Then just added the bootstrap script and css CDN to the project and it works fine

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh1a31sv/)

Be sure to include these in your `<head>` section if you don't have them already.

If you downloaded the files and they are located in your project directory I would suggest you replace the references to those files and use a CDN it makes loading faster and you are less likely to run into issues with missing scripts or styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used bootply and all I did was change the data-target class:

### [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mtADcx5a9I)

make sure the class you are targeting is the same class your bootstrap modal has.

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".thisClass" id="about-btn"><i class="fa fa-question-circle white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a></li>

<div class="modal fade thisClass" id="aboutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
..........<!--the rest of your code-->
```